# Discrete Math (Combination with repetition)

Tags: analysis, discrete-mathematics

### Question:

The employee is distributing 7 objects among 4 containrs (Xi's).

Assuming the containers are X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 = 7 where Xi >= 0   $\forall$ 1<= i <= 4.

Determine all integer solutions.

### Logical Questions:

1. How do we understand this question involves combination with repetition ?

---

- My answer: Order does not matter, and we are allowed to place as many objects we can inside a container which suggests repetition is allowed, so we use combination with repetition $n + r - 1 \choose r$. Am I right?

---

2. What is n and what is r ? (I don't understand this).

---

- My answer: To me at first, I thought the number of containers were the limiting factor, so r = 4, and n = 7. However, the objects are the limiting factors I believe ?

---

Comment: I just need confirmation to see if I am on the right track.

Comment: I believe we consider a number as our r when it is the limiting factor. Am I right ?

Comment: I think that the objects are a limiting factor because you can only move 3 of them, because of that condition that says that every container should have at least 1 object inside.

Comment: @JuanIgnacioCuiule, I do believe the objects are the limiting factor, so r = 7. How do you know every container X1 ... X4 gets atleast one object ? I mean, to me I think you can have an empty container because it did not explicitly mention that every container needs to be filled.

Comment: "Assuming the containers are X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 = 7 where Xi > 0 ∀ 1<= i <= 4."
It says that the sum of all should be 7 and that for every container (Xi) the value should be greater than 0

Comment: In the previous case you were right, but the actual question has greater or equal to, so a container can be left empty.

Comment: Why can't this just be stars and bars instead of "combinations with repetitions"?

Comment: @Kourosh look at this [video](https://youtu.be/ZcSSI6VY1kM?t=238) , I think that it can help you.

Comment: Yes indeed, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

1. Any counting problem that does not need order, and repetitions are allowed for its objects, then you can use combinations with repetition. Equation: $n+r-1\choose r$
2. Your limiting factor is your r, so in this question the limiting factor is your number of objects, 7, and your total, n is your number of containers.

   $\therefore$ $r = 7$,  $n = 4$

   $\therefore$ $4+7-1\choose 7$ = $10\choose 7$